# How can i insert 10 seconds of silent audio(null audio without images or video or black video) into video repeat every 15 seconds with ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, render, edit

I have a clip `video.mp4` . How can i insert 10 seconds of only silent audio into  this clip repeat every 15 seconds until the end of this clip with ffmpeg? 
I know `anullsrc` is an audio so i can't use `overlay` filter. I research on google for a while but the only option i have is `gte(mod(t,15),10))`.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want 0-10, 25-35, 50-60, 75-85... silent?

Comment: Yes, I want 0-10, 25-35, 50-60, 75-85... silent and without video

Comment: "without video", so black?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i in -vf drawbox=t=fill:enable='lt(mod(t,25),10)' -af volume=0::enable='lt(mod(t,25),10)' out
```

This will make time ranges 0-10, 25-35, 50-60.. have silent audio and a black image.

---

```
ffmpeg -i in -af volume=0::enable='lt(mod(t,25),10)' -c:v copy out
```

This will not alter the video.

Comment: No I don't need black video
Can you fix to only contain silent audio generated from `anullsrc` in time ranges 0-10, 25-35, 50-60.. ?

Comment: Can you please help me, I don't know how to insert `anullsrc` into this clip

Comment: Can you help me,please?